# H2: open connection, update, close connection and now all my changes are gone?

Tags: java, sql, database, jdbc, h2

I am opening a database connection to H2 with the following URL:

```
jdbc:h2:../webapps/h2_db/MyDB;MODE=MySQL
```

I go and create a table with a Statement. Then when I am done I close my connection. Then when I open a new connection and check for that table it is NOT there. It looks like H2 wipes out everything I have done with a connection once it is closed. Of course I need by database to persist across connections.

What am I missing here? I am using H2 in file mode, so I see the MyDB.h2.db file.

Thanks!

Comment: The file was being deleted by mistake, and a new file was being created when the connection was being re-opened. Sorry, by bad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might need to commit the message after you make. Im not sure of the exact syntax here but often its something like `dbcursor.commit()`